# Problem casting field when querying spreadsheet

Tags: sql, vbscript, spreadsheet

I am trying to query an .xls spreadsheet with VBScript, but I have run into an issue when trying to cast a field.  
I connect to the spreadsheet like this.

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DataSource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"
```

Then I try to query the spreadsheet.  The field I am interested in contains decimal values, but can also contain a * as a wildcard.  So what I'm trying to do is cast the field to a varchar so I can check for the *.

```
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE F1 >= 2.3456 OR CAST(F1 AS VARCHAR) = '*'"
objRecordset.Open StrQuery, objConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

This causes an unspecified error 80004005.  What am I doing wrong here? 
 NOTE: I also tried CONVERT, but got an Undefined Function error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to  append `IMEX=1;` to the extended properties. That tells JET DB to read mixed numbers, dates and strings as text.  Then you should be able to:

```
SELECT * FROM [F1$]
```

That is, if `F1` is the name of the first worksheet.

Comment: I need to compare numeric values in the field as well, so making them strings would cause more problems. Say I have a query like
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE F1 >= 2.34 AND CAST(F1 AS VARCHAR) = '*'

Comment: Read the entire sheet, and do the filtering in vbscript?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid, since I would think a query would run a lot faster than a filter I would write.

Comment: I sort of combined the ideas and filtered the results of a simpler query with VBScript, this allowed me to process less data with VBScript.  I limited my query to text fields, and used VBScript to filter the mixed value fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the following registry keys on your server (after having a backup of course):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\ImportMixedTypes = Text
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows = 0
```

I would also modify your connection string to the following:

```
Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/PathTo/YourFile/" & Filename) & ";"
If chkUploadFileColumnsFirstRow.Checked Then
  sConnectionString &= "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
Else
  sConnectionString &= "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1'"
End If
```

If it fails after setting those criteria, I would feel something is wrong with either your sheet name, or the query itself.

Comment: I need to compare numeric values in the field as well, so making them strings would cause more problems. Say I have a query like SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE F1 >= 2.34 AND CAST(F1 AS VARCHAR) = '*'

Comment: I use the SqlBulkCopy class and read data from the spreadsheet, and import it into a temporary table which then matches the data types you are looking to compare to.  If you read in all strings, you can make assumptions about data types in the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Microsoft Jet 4.0 engine does not support the `CAST()` function, nor does it has a `VARCHAR` keyword (nor `VARCHAR` data type, come to that). Why do you need to cast this value? Do you need to handle the `NULL` value?

Speaking of data types:

```
F1 >= 2.3456
```

The value `2.3456` is a literal of type `DECIMAL` being fixed point decimal. Excel has no native fixed decimal type so you are most likely comparing a floating point value to fixed point value.. I trust you appreciate the problems this can cause!

Comment: Thank you, but the only problem I am having is when I'm looking for the wildcard character (*).  The numerical values are being compared fine, I just can't get it to return records that contain the * in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate

```
F1 >= 2.3456
```

suggests `F1` is a numeric data type. Please explain how you can cast a numeric value to `VARCHAR` and expect to get `*` as a result...? I can't see it happening myself!

If your column contains numeric values and `*` characters then it will be of mixed types and the Jet 4.0 engine needs to to decide whether to choose `FLOAT` (in which case your * characters will be replaced by the `NULL` value) or of type `NVARCHAR(255)` (in which case your numeric values *may* be converted to scientific notation).

You may be able to use registry values to influence the result but have no hope of doing it in the SQL code because the data type has already been chosen.

More more details see [Daily Dose of Excel: External Data - Mixed Data Types](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/) by a so-called expert :) There's a lot of good detail buried in the comments.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the records that contain a * in the field?  Do I just have to return records where that field is null?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

1. remove the `CAST` and `VARCHAR` keywords
   from your query (they are illegal);
2. change the local machine registry
   key `TypeGuessRows = 0` (force to scan
   scan all rows should determine the
   column is of mixed types...);
3. ensure the local machine registry
   key `ImportMixedTypes = Text` (...to
   import mixed types as text, being
   the default value). See previous answers for details.

Once done your '*' characters will appear in the column (i.e. will no longer be `NULL`). However, your float values will have been coerced to text. You can cast/coerce the float-as-text values back to being numeric in the SQL but first you will have to test for `NULL` and a numeric value e.g.

```
SELECT F1, 
       IIF(
           F1 IS NULL, 
           '{{Excel cell is blank}}', 
           IIF(
               F1 = '*', 
               '{{Excel cell is the ''*'' character}}', 
               IIF(
                   ISNUMERIC(F1), 
                   CDBL(F1), 
                   '{{Excel cell is non-nmeric and not the ''*'' character}}'
                  )
              )
       ) AS result       
FROM [F1$];
```

Note I'd normally prefer `SWITCH()` over nest `IIF()` but in this case it must be `IIF()`. Reason: `IIF()` if overloaded for Access Database Engine SQL and either the `TRUE` or the `FALSE` condition will be evaluated but never both. In VBA the opposite is the case i.e. both conditions are always evaluated. `SWITCH()` does not shortcut, either in Access Database Engine SQL or VBA.